# How to use twitter callback event

Tags: php, twitter

```
<script>
!function(d,s,id)
{
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id))
    {
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
}
(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="URL_TO_SHARE" data-counturl="URL_TO_SHARE">Tweet</a>
```

Please look above code which is working fine.

I have integrated twitter share button on my website. Now i want to give some benefits to the user who have shared link via twitter.
So i want to use a call back event on success, from where i can call my customized code or `ajax` call.

Same functionality is provided by Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211902/custom-twitter-tweet-button-callback-does-not-work-for-first-click-but-works-t) might help you with some modification. Move the

```
twttr.events.bind('tweet',function(event){
           alert('Here');
           //Code that uses unique_id here;
    });
```

outside the function. Haven't test, but I think it should be worked.